# How to change font size of table in Rmarkdown, LaTeX and .pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

I have a document that I create, based on data from different banks and for staff across different locations and roles. My .Rmd file is as follows:

````
---
title: <center> <h1>Output Report</h1> </center>
mainfont: Arial
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
sansfont: Arial
fig_crop: false
toc: true
classoption: landscape
fontsize: 11pt
geometry: margin=0.45in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{sectsty} \sectionfont{\centering}
- \renewcommand{\contentsname}{}\vspace{-2cm} 
---
<style>
  .main-container {
    max-width: 1200px !important;
  }
</style>

```{r load myData, include=FALSE}
load("C:/Desktop/RawData.RData")
```

```{r global_options, R.options=knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)}
```
\newpage

# Client One 

```{r fig.width=18, fig.height=6, echo=FALSE, comment=" "}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(subset(Durations, Client == "Client One")) +
  aes(x = NumStart, y = Value) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = NumStart, xmax = NumEnd,
                ymin = 0, ymax = 0.8, 
                fill = Position)) + 
  geom_text(data=Inv[Inv$Client == "Client One",], 
            aes(x = Median, y = Value, 
            label = Symbol), 
            size = 4.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=myColors) +
 scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.015, 0.015)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),limits = c(0, 0.8),
                     labels = c("F50", "FMID", "DMID", "D50"), 
                     breaks = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.key.size = unit(1.25, 'lines'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face = "bold"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15, colour = "black"), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", colour = "black", size = 10),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.line.y = element_blank(), 
        panel.spacing = unit(0.5, "lines"), 
        strip.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 15, face = "bold")) +
  facet_wrap(~ Bank, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x")
```
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

t1 <- kable({x <- subset(Inv_Location, Client=="Client One", select = Location:DE);
             names(x) <- sprintf("\\textbf{%s}", names(x))
             x},
            format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
            align = 'c', escape = FALSE)
t2 <- kable({x <- subset(Inv_Role, Client == "Client One", select = Role:DE);
             names(x) <- sprintf("\\textbf{%s}", names(x))
             x},
            format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
            align = 'c', escape = FALSE)
t3 <- kable({x <- subset(Inv_ByRotation, Client == "Client One", select = Rotation:IPM);
             names(x) <- sprintf("\\textbf{%s}", names(x))
             x},
            format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
            align = 'c', escape = FALSE)
t4 <- kable({x <- subset(Season_InvByLocation, Client == "Client One", select = Location:DE);
             names(x) <- sprintf("\\textbf{%s}", names(x))
             x},
            format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
            align = 'c', escape = FALSE)
t5 <- kable({x <- subset(Season_InvByRole, Client == "Client One", select = Role:DE);
             names(x) <- sprintf("\\textbf{%s}", names(x))
             x},
            format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
            align = 'c', digits = 2, escape = FALSE)

cat(c("\\begin{table}[!htb]
 \\centering 
    \\begin{minipage}{.20\\linewidth}
      \\centering 
      \\textbf{Bank - By Location}
      \\centering",
        t1,
    "\\end{minipage}%
    \\centering
    \\begin{minipage}{.35\\linewidth}
     \\centering 
      \\textbf{Bank - By Role}",
        t2,
    "\\end{minipage}%
    \\centering 
    \\begin{minipage}{.25\\linewidth}
      \\centering 
      \\textbf{Bank - By Rotation}",
        t3,
    "\\end{minipage} 
\\end{table}"
)) 
cat(c("\\begin{table}[!htb]
 \\centering 
    \\begin{minipage}{.25\\linewidth}
      \\centering 
      \\textbf{Bank - By Location }",
        t4,
    "\\end{minipage}%
 \\centering 
    \\begin{minipage}{.35\\linewidth}
      \\centering 
      \\textbf{Bank - By Role}",
        t5,
    "\\end{minipage} 
\\end{table}"
)) 
```
````

I now wish to simply change the font size of the tables - it is simply too big and overlapping into seperate pages.

Is it possible to do this, given my end output is a .pdf and I am using `kable` to create these tables?

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe you can try out the `kableExtra` package. To change font size, you can try

```
kable(x, "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 7)
```

Or, you can try to use the `scale_down` option, which will automatically scale the table to page width using the LaTeX `graphicx` package.

```
kable(x, "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down")
```

You can read the full vignette here: http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf
http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html